# How to Python count list length

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to know how len() works.

Does it count from beginning to end of a list every time I call len(), or, since list is also an class, does len() just return a variable in the list object which record the list's length?

Also, I hope someone can tell me where I can find the source code of those built-in functions like 'len()', 'map()', etc.

Comment: It calls the `__len__` method of the list object. You can view the source here: http://svn.python.org/view/python/tags/r27/Objects/listobject.c?view=markup

Comment: it keeps track of its length so it does not recount each time ...

Comment: And here's the source for the builtins: http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.4/file/9290822f2280/Python/bltinmodule.c#l928

Comment: @RobertBean for what reason would you expect a list **not** to know it's length at all times?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Download Python 2.7 source code here: http://www.python.org/getit/releases/2.7.4/

`list` is implemented in `./Include/listobject.h` and `./Objects/listobject.c`.

```c
typedef struct {
    PyObject_VAR_HEAD
    /* Vector of pointers to list elements.  list[0] is ob_item[0], etc. */
    PyObject **ob_item;

    /* ob_item contains space for 'allocated' elements.  The number
     * currently in use is ob_size.
     * Invariants:
     *     0 <= ob_size <= allocated
     *     len(list) == ob_size
     *     ob_item == NULL implies ob_size == allocated == 0
     * list.sort() temporarily sets allocated to -1 to detect mutations.
     *
     * Items must normally not be NULL, except during construction when
     * the list is not yet visible outside the function that builds it.
     */
    Py_ssize_t allocated;
} PyListObject;
```

`list.__len__()` just consults `ob_size`, which is part of `PyObject_VAR_HEAD`. This makes `len()` a constant-time operation for lists.

Comment: You should probably  include PyObject_VAR_HEAD since that is most relevant.

Comment: Direct link to header file source: https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Include/listobject.h

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can find the documentation of the built-in functions [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html).

The `list` data-type keeps track of the number of elements it's holding, `len(list)` is an O(1) operation.

---

For the source code, you can find the source code of Python at [the download page](http://www.python.org/getit/releases/2.7.4/).