# 'What is magic about __len__()?

Tags: python

So a list object does not have a simple length attribute `len` but rather the "magic" `__len__()`. Why is it preferred to use the function `len()` on a list rather than its attribute? Does the function `len()` not simply query `__len__()`? Why that detour and not have `my_list.len()`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496009/is-there-any-case-where-lensomeobj-does-not-call-someobjs-len-function/497096#497096

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any case where len(someObj) does not call someObj's \_\_len\_\_ function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496009/is-there-any-case-where-lensomeobj-does-not-call-someobjs-len-function)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16249418/how-to-python-count-list-length

Comment: [You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) ["Why?" questions on language design do not fit this criteria.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170394/what-is-the-rationale-for-closing-why-questions-on-a-language-design)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It might be helpful to think of `__len__` as a method you can customize for any object.  Part of the reason for the `len` function vs using `.__len__()` or `.len()` is that python was intended to be a language that is easy to learn.  For a beginner programmer, understanding that you use the length function to get the length of a list seems very intuitive to me.

For example:

```
class MyObject:
     def __len__(self):
          return 100

a = MyObject()
assert len(a) == 100
```

So it's just a construct of all python objects that you can set how length is calculated.  This example isn't useful, but perhaps if you had a Circle object, you might want length to be it's Circumference, ie.

```
 class Circle:
     def __init__(self, radius):
         self.radius = radius

     def __len__(self):
         return 3.14 * self.radius * 2
```

A benefit of having `len` as a function as well as a method is the ability to map-filter-reduce len onto arrays.  It is very easy to write:

```
map(len, [[1, 2], [4, 5, 6]])
```

However, if you really think that `.len()` is an attractive way to present the length of an object, you could just add a method.

```
class MyObject:
    def __len__(self):
        return 10
    def len(self):
        return len(self)
```

Comment: Thank you, Rob. Spot on, that was really helpful!